# How do I forward declare a template type that has been forward declared elsewhere with a defaulting

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, forward-declaration, default-arguments

So the excellent answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48282811/2642059) states that you can default template types in a forward declaration, however:

> You can specify each default template argument only once

This is more fully specified in the linked question, but Boost's Property Tree stuff works with the `ptree` type:

```
typedef basic_ptree<std::string, std::string> ptree;
```

But the `basic_ptree` class is defined like this:

```
template<class Key, class Data, class KeyCompare>
class basic_ptree
```

The only reason the `ptree` `typedef` is defined with only 2 template parameters is that before it's `typedef` there is the forward declaration:

```
template < class Key, class Data, class KeyCompare = std::less<Key> >
class basic_ptree;
```

---

This brings me to my actual question. I need to pass around a `ptree`. But I don't want to include `Boost` in my headers. This means that I'll have to forward declare. *But I can't match the defaulted forward declaration because the default can only be declared once.*

**How can I write a forward declaration and forward typedef that depends upon the defaulting in another headers forward declaration?**

I'm currently doing this, but that means I'm *not* forward `typedef`'ing, I'm making a *new* `typedef`:

```
template <class Key, class Data, class KeyCompare> class basic_ptree;
typedef basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>> ptree;
```

For the sake of consistency I want to depend on the same defaulted forward declaration of `basic_ptree` that the original `ptree` `typedef` depended upon.

Comment: I'm currently doing this, but that means I'm not forward typedeffing, I'm making a *new* typedef: `template <class Key, class Data, class KeyCompare> class basic_ptree; typedef basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>> ptree;` And I don't want to make my own typedef for fear of inconsistency.

Comment: Ah, why add your current approach in the tight space of a comment?

Comment: @StoryTeller I thought there was too much already in the question. It was getting overwhelming. Do you not think so?

Comment: Personally, i'd rather see another 10 line segments (`---`), instead of parsing code from comments (it's groan inducing for me personally).

Comment: is it really so bad to just include the "*ptree_fwd.hpp*" header ?

Comment: @StoryTeller Alright I've rolled it into the question, but rather than recognizing it as the mandatory C++ downvote, I'm going to blame your edit for the inevitable downvote.

Comment: Have an advance then

Comment: @StoryTeller Ha, thanks that softens the forthcoming blow :)

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes That's a pretty subjective answer. But suffice to say for the purposes of this question, `#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>` would not be a well received answer!

Comment: My comment was not intended to be provocative, I'm just trying to understand what are you asking for; you already know this is not possible in a literal way, so I guess you're looking for some kind of workaround; now, in order to suggest it (like using a template alias, or exploting ptree's include guards), we'd need to know better what do you mean by "*But I don't want to include Boost*" and "*I want to depend on the same defaulted forward declaration*" ... BTW, the *ptree_fwd.hpp* header *is* the way boost devs do it, so it would be informative to know what's exactly wrong in using it ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I'm more interested in the academy of a solution. That is to say I wanted there to be a way to do this, though it seems there's not :( So in that case it is very likely that your suggestion of `#include <boost/property_tree/ptree_fwd.hpp>` is my best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. You either have to guarantee somehow that the other declaration will never be included so you can specify your own default, or you need to depend on that other declaration.

But I get the feeling this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), for the following statement:

> But I don't want to include Boost in my headers.

Why not? Your code is obviously dependent on Boost's `ptree`, so anyone working with your code would have to have Boost installed anyway. If you want your declarations to also compile when Boost isn't installed, there are several options:

- Make sure you exclude the bits that use `ptree` using preprocessor directives (`#if`/`#endif` blocks)
- Use C++17's `__has_include()` to test for the existence of `<boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>`, and then either include it if it exists, or declare your own `ptree` if it doesn't.

Comment: The use of `ptree` is internal to my implementation layer's header. It is important that my interface layer does not pull in Boost.